# Python with Beautiful Soup not looping through pages.

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey guys this is my first post. I am a marketer (ewww) and I am new to Python so please don't shoot me.

I am learning through trial and error, hacking scripts like this one.

Can anyone tell me how to loop through all pages of the website and then print the info for each url?

```
url = "http://example.com"

urls = [url] # Stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] # Record of scraped urls
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()


# While stack of urls is greater than 0, keep scraping for links
while len(urls) > 0:
try:
    htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()

# Except for visited urls
except:
    print urls[0]

# Get and Print Information
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "lxml")
urls.pop(0)
info = soup.findAll(['title', 'h1', 'h2', 'p'])
for script in soup("script"):
soup.script.extract()

print info

# Number of URLs in stack
print len(urls)

# Append Incomplete Tags
for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
    if url in tag['href'] and tag['href'] not in visited:
        urls.append(tag['href'])
        visited.append(tag['href'])
```

Comment: The way you would scrape one website's pages usually differs, often quite considerably, from how you would scrape another's pages. In fact, sometimes BeautifulSoup works, sometimes not. Each of us builds up a collection of skills that we can apply to more and more pages. You should try scraping one site and if you can't complete the task show us your code and ask specific questions about what you need to understand.

Comment: Thanks bill, I'll take the feedback on board for all future posts. I can get this script to run successfully however it scrapes the same page over and over. I think the specific issue lies somewhere in the "# Append Incomplete Tags" section, urlparse.urljoin seems to be using the same url instead of moving to the next follow link.. if I am on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

- I see `visited` mentioned twice. In once instance, it's used as a list of urls, in the other as a list of HTML elements. This is very naughty.
- In the `while` loop each url is solicited from its site and read into `htmltext` barring an `exception`. Notice though that, each time through the loop the previous contents of `htmltext` will be *overwritten* and lost. BeautifulSoup must be called each time `htmltext` is made available and then the `soup` from BeautifulSoup processed before `soup` is created again.

Following your style I would write the bare bones of code like this in this way.

```
import requests
import bs4

urls = ['url_1', 'url_2', 'url_3', 'url_4', 'url_5', 'url_6', 'url_7', 'url_8', 'url_9', 'url_10']

while urls:
    url = urls.pop(0)
    print (url)
    try:
        htmltext = requests.get(url).content
    except:
        print ('*** attempt to open '+url+' failed')
        continue
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmltext, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find('title')
    print (title)
```

- I use the requests library rather than urllib because it usually makes life easier.
- Since you use the `pop` method of the `urls` list to remove its items we don't need to keep a record of `visited` urls. As they're eliminated from `urls` the list becomes shorter and eventually becomes empty.
- `while urls` asks whether `urls` is empty or not.
- The **main point** of this code is that it shows how interrogating the remote site and calling BeautifulSoup are in the same loop that spins through the list `urls`.